# how to show UART received data (on PIN 10, RX) of Raspberry pi on Tkinter Window

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pic, uart

I have a slave pic which will transmit some data to Raspberry pi depending on switch pressed(connected to pic) using UART. I want to show the message which is coming on RX pin of raspberry pi to Tkinter window. what is the procedure to do so??

Comment: Take a look at the PySerial module of Python.

Comment: Actually i am new to UART. I have a tkinter window. i want print some value which is coming on RX port of RPI. please help.

Comment: Mr vermaete kindly provide me a sample programme which will monitor RX pin .if a data is available it will store the data in a variable and also print the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import serial, time, struct

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)



while True:

    count = 0
    AValue = []
    for ch in ser.read():
        if ch == "\n":
            AValue = []
            time.sleep(0.1)

    while count < 4:
        for ch in ser.read():
            AValue.append(ch)
            count += 1
```

im using this code to recive four bytes of code (float) from pic. you can go from there